# Reverse Geo Coding in R

Tags: r

I would like to reverse geo code address and pin code in R

These are the columns

```
A                    B             C    
15.3859085     74.0314209   7J7P92PJ+9H77QGCCCC
```

I have taken first four rows having columns A B and C among 1000's of rows

```
df<-ga.data[1:4,]  

df <- cbind(df,do.call(rbind,
                       lapply(1:nrow(df),
                              function(i) 
                                revgeocode(as.numeric(
                                  df[i,3:1]), output = "more")      
                              [c("administrative_area_level_1","locality","postal_code","address")])))
```

> Error in revgeocode(as.numeric(df[i, 3:1]), output = "more") : 
>     is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 2 is not TRUE

Also is there any other package or approach to find out the address and pincode most welcome

I also tried the following 
When I tried using ggmap I got this error

> ```
> In revgeocode(as.numeric(df[i, c("Latitude", "Longitude")]), output = "address") :
>   HTTP 400 Bad Request
> ```

Also i tried this

```
revgeocode(c(df$B[1], df$A[1]))
```

> Warning Warning message: In revgeocode(c(df$Longitude[1],
>   df$Latitude[1])) : HTTP 400 Bad Request

Also I am from India and it does not work for me if i search for lat long of India. If I use lat long of US it gives me the exact address

seems fishy

```
data <- read.csv(text="ID,      Longitude,      Latitude
311175,  41.298437,      -72.929179
292058,  41.936943,      -87.669838
12979,   37.580956,      -77.471439")

library(ggmap)
result <- do.call(rbind,
                  lapply(1:nrow(data),
                         function(i)revgeocode(as.numeric(data[i,3:2]))))
data <- cbind(data,result)
```

Comment: Where did you find this `revgeocode()`? - It's not base R. Please include any packages you might be using

Comment: i am not able to find any suitable package. I need reverse geo code to work on the lat and long data

Comment: No, I mean which package did you use to get the function `revgeocode`?

Comment: i used library revgeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current CRAN version of revgeo_0.15 does not have the revgeocode function. If you upgrade to this version, you'll find a `revgeo` function, which takes longitude, latitude arguments. Your column C should not be passed into the function.

```
    revgeo::revgeo(latitude=df[, 'A'], longitude=df[, 'B'], output='frame')
    [1] "Getting geocode data from Photon: http://photon.komoot.de/reverse?lon=74.0314209&lat=15.3859085"
                 housenumber           street  city state                zip country
    1 House Number Not Found Street Not Found Borim   Goa Postcode Not Found   India
```

Comment: Are you not getting the same output as I am? Or are you getting a different output? Or an error message? Please elaborate on 'not working for me'. Did you check that you're passing in the correct fields for latitude and longitude?